# Can someone please tell me what is wrong this? and yes i just started learning c#

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace superboombastic
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int [] a = {};
            Console.Write("please enter your name: ");
            string b = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Hi! " + b);

            while (true) 
            { 
                Console.Write("Please enter Age: ");
                int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                a = new int[c];
                string e = "yes";

                Console.Write("Do you want to continue? ");
                string h = Console.ReadLine();

                if (h != e)
                { break; }
            }
            
            Array.ForEach(a, Console.WriteLine);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is the list to be printed after the user is done adding the values, but what is printing at the end is just a bunch of zeroes. So, please whosoever knows what I have done wrong, please enlighten me.

Comment: This is a great opportunity for you to go step by step in your code and figure out what's wrong. Hint, the (current) main problem is inside the loop, and can be seen even from the first run of the loop

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. When you say "the list", which list do you want to be printed? What I mean is, can you describe exactly what you would like to be shown on screen after the user is done?

Comment: You're creating a new array with the size set to the input age rather than adding the number to the array.  I'd suggest using a `List<int>` instead and the `Add` method.

Comment: wait imma post the output

Comment: Unless you're working with a very odd version of C#, feel free to use *longer meaningful names* for your variables. They'll help you (and others) better understand what you intended each of them to mean.

Comment: please enter your name: Bruh
Hi! Bruh
Please enter Age: 17
Do you want to continue? yes
Please enter Age: 18
Do you want to continue? yes
Please enter Age: 19
Do you want to continue? no
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

Comment: @HeavyDriver0925 Notice how it's printing 19 zeros which is exactly the last age you entered.  `new int[c];` where c is 19 will create a new array of size 19 with default values which is 0 for `int`.

Comment: Alright @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'll use better-named variables from next time

Comment: oh my god @juharr thanks dude I think I know what I did wrong, this is probably because of me learning python as my first language 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you have 2 examples, one with an array and other with a list

```
// With an array
int[] myArray = new int[] { 10, 20, 30 };
// Ex : Print with a For loop
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myArray[i]);
}
// Ex : Print with a Foreach loop
foreach (int item in myArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}


// With a list
List<int> myList = new List<int>() { 40, 50, 60 };
// Ex : Print with a For loop
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myList.ElementAt(i));
}
// Ex : Print with a Foreach loop
foreach (int item in myList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Please mark this answer as correct if that helps.

Comment: thank you so much, my man, the examples helped a lot. I'm still struggling though as the first language I learnt was python and man oh man was that easy. So, yeah I'm gonna be using lists from now on because I used to use lists in python too and yeah I fixed the whole code too, so thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome, i'm glad this helped you. Keep going ;)
Please mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace superboombastic
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> ageList = new List<int>();
            Console.Write("please enter your name: ");
            string userName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hi! " + userName);
            bool exitLoop = false;
            while (!exitLoop)
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter Age: ");
                int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                ageList.Add(age);
                string e = "yes";
                Console.Write("Do you want to continue? ");
                string h = Console.ReadLine();
                if (h != e)
                { 
                    exitLoop = true;
                }
            }
            foreach (var a in ageList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I made some changes to the code based on what I believe you are trying to accomplish.

you were creating a new array in the loop each time, and then printing a new array of size age, which had nothing in it.

Instead let's create a list that you can add too each time the user adds an age to the list, then foreach over the list printing each value.

I also took the liberty in adding some more descriptive variables.

Comment: `please enter your name: asdasd

Hi! asdasd
Please enter Age: 1
Do you want to continue? yes
Please enter Age: 2
Do you want to continue? yes
Please enter Age: 3
Do you want to continue? yes
Please enter Age: 4
Do you want to continue? n
1
2
3
4
`

This is the output that I get in visual studio, is that the intended output? the question was not clear on what you want to happen.